# Web Audio API is cutting out the higher frequencies on weaker devices

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm trying to detect very high (18000+) frequencies using javascript and the Web Audio API through a browser. My code currently works fine on my laptop, but when I try to run it on a weaker device (a raspberry pi or Chromebook) I notice that the upper end of the frequencies are not being detected. This occurs even on established demos like https://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html, where I notice a singular bar appearing after playing a very high note on my laptop but not on a raspberry pi or Chromebook.

I've tested it using the same microphone across all devices. I've also tried setting a much lower FFT size, in case it was a speed issue. Does anyone have any input?

Comment: A small example showing how you're doing this would be really great.

Comment: raspberry doesn't have a native analog audio input (check frequency-range specs of your analog input solution). Can you use some 'native' (non html5 app) software to record a PCM wave file on the lower end devices and analyze the waveform (in audacity, reaper or whatever) to see if the device picked up the frequency? Also try to test on at least 2 different browsers (suggesting chrome and ff). You're trying to further narrow down the problem: is it in the browser or a limitation of the device (or it's audio settings)? Also try running an example of sonicnet.js ...

Comment: 1) what rate is the audio device running at?

Comment: 2) It's likely, if the audio device isn't running at too low a sample rate, that you're not properly getting all the pre-processing turned off, or it just plain CAN'T be turned off.  (Some audio devices do high-frequency rolloffs or the like because it sounds better for speech.)